# System.Environment.CurrentDirectory returns wrong Directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have added a NUnit test project to a project in order to make unit tests. My main project is in:

```
C:\Users\myName\Desktop\0120-project\ProjectName\
```

Unit test project is in:

```
C:\Users\myName\Desktop\0120-project\ProjectNameTest\
```

Now when I'm debugging a unit test:

```
[Test]
public void ExportationTest()
{
    var evan = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    //...           
}
```

the returned value of `evan` is:

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharperPlatformVs12
```

how is that even possible?! I'm not even launching the project from there.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Your *test* is running out of that directory.  @JuanRomero is correct.

Comment: The executable running the test *is* in that directory.

Comment: @amy Not necessarily - it's enough that that's the current working directory. The binary can  be elsewhere

Comment: @fredrik yes, and if the binary were elsewhere, the current working directory would reflect that.

Comment: @amy it might. You can stand in ´C:\´ and run a binary located somewhere else, the working directory would be ´C:\´ anyway.

Comment: @fredrik i'm aware of that.

Comment: I believe the accepted answer is wrong, NUnit provides a property for the current //test// directory ``TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory``, which should work irrespective of how the test is run (VS, or Resharper, or a CI build server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **Environment.CurrentDirectory Property**
>
> Gets or sets the fully qualified path of the current working
> directory.

It looks like you are using ReSharper to launch your tests, which is probably setting the working directory to that location.

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix the problem :

I have found this solution that fixed my problem :

```
   [Test]
         public void ExportationTest()
         {
       Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
           var evan= System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
             //...           
         }
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\myName\Desktop\0120-project\ProjectNameTest\
```

P.S : Will work on Desktop based application, not sure for web based applications like asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Nunit has a property called `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` which you should have been using since version 3 came out.

Comment: Yes this is also an alternative way to fix the problem , Unfortunately I discovered it after accepting the answer. Also , writing this in the default test constructor is also a remedy to the problem   `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);`

Answer (score 0):

use

`Application.StartupPath`

inested of

`Environment.CurrentDirectory`